# How do you change a paragraphs/headers colour if the body already has a color?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have given my `<body>` a color (`blue`) and I would like to make one of the headers (`<h3>`) in the body a different color (`green`) without using the `id`. I am trying to make all `<h3>` headers a certain color.

When I open the code in a browser I get the following:

```css
body {
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h3 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: green;
  font-family: serif;
}
#id1 {
  color: blue;
}
span {
  color: orange;
}
.id4 {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Question1</title>
  <link href="question1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="id1">This is a silly header</h3>
  <h2 id="id2">First h2 heading this is.</h2>
  <p>Mares eat oats</p>
  <span> and this is a span</span>
  <p>and this is yet more text in the second paragraph.</p>
  <p id="id3">This is a third paragraph.</p>
  <p class="id4">May the fourth paragraph be with you.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How about removing `#id1 {color: blue;}`?

Comment: I guess I'm confused, why wouldn't you want to use IDs to perform this?

Comment: @PaulRandall lets just say its an assignment that asks you not to use and ID

Comment: @MarkoStojsic, let me know if my answer correctly interprets your question. I can revise it if necessary, or if it's not useful I will delete.

Comment: You probably helped the most actualy, thanks. @Michael_B

Comment: @MarkoStojsic I still don’t understand why you don’t simply remove the `#id1 {color: blue;}` from your CSS.

Comment: @Xufox If i remove that, nothing will change. What I am trying to do is to make the h3 header green where as it's appearing as blue in this piece of code.

Comment: @MarkoStojsic It does change for me. Removing the above mentioned line will achieve exactly that because exactly that line overrides the green color.

Comment: @Xufox Lets just say this was a practice question with instructions given to specifically make #id1 blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h3
{
    font-style: italic;
    color: green !important;
    font-family: serif;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/k5pcdvkz/

EDIT: The question requires that the `id` attribute in the `h3` not be used for styling. Hence, the `id` styles must be overridden to apply the green color. `!important` is an effective tool in this case.

Comment: Why use `!important` if it could be done better way?

Comment: @YuraYakym, the question says we cannot use the `ID`. So it needs to be overridden. If it could be done a better way then please post your answer

Comment: @YuraYakym, My impression from the question was that the `ID` was off-limits.

Answer (score -2):

Shortly:

`h3:nth-child(1) { color:green; }`

Details:

[codepen demo link](http://codepen.io/pgmrhd/pen/xwYXgm)

You can use **`nth-child`** property that is new in CSS3. It choose the elements by number. It starts with number 1 and the number is **defined by order of siblings**, but little bit confusing. However, only with following one example you can use it easily. I'll show you it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
        <li>list 3</li>
        <div></div>
        <li>list 4</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, you can apply your style at each of `<li>` elements. But please see carefully for 4th `<li>`.

```
ul li:nth-child(1) { color:red; }
ul li:nth-child(2) { color:blue; }
ul li:nth-child(3) { color:green; }
/* 4th <li> is not nth-child(4), but nth-child(5) because of <div> element. */
ul li:nth-child(5) { color:pink; }
```

I don't know the reason why, but the `nth-child` method **counts other sibling together**. Then, in your case, you can use like this.

```
h3:nth-child(1) { color:green; }
```

I'm sure you'll be use it without difficulty. Have a nice day with HTML5~!

Comment: Isn't this effective? @Xufox

Comment: This is over-complicated and the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for typing error for </body> to <body> in HTML and annotation in CSS. I fixed it. I thought this solution is better than setting lots of ids... but it wasn't for you. Sorry again. @Xufox

Comment: That’s not the only thing. `<div>`s aren’t allowed as children of `<ul>`s.